# How to suppress linker warnings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, linker, warnings, xcode7

I get annoying warnings like shown below and want to suppress them.

```
warning: (arm64)  could not find object file symbol for symbol _ff_h264_idct_add_neon
```

My app uses CocoaPods for its dependencies and one of the dependencies is FFmpeg-iOS.

How can I suppress all warnings about missing object file symbols or all linker warnings?